# Function with two variables.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Show that, for $x\ge4$ when $-1\le a<0$, following function

$f(x,a)=x(x+3)^{a-1}(a+1)+3(x+3)^{a-1}+a(x+2)^{a-1}$

is decreasing.

I tried is fixed one variable and differentiating w.r.t to other but its getting worse. i.e.

$f'(x_0,a)=x_0(x_0+3)^{a-1}log(x_0+3)(a+1)+x_0(x_0+3)^{a-1}+3(x_0+3)^{a-1}log(x_0+3)+(x_0+2)^{a-1}+a(x_0+2)^{a-1}log(x_0+2)$

Comment: Is decreasing in $a$, $x$ or both?

Comment: Decreasing in both.